# How to deny identical images being uploaded with PHP

Tags: php, image, upload, directory, duplicates

I want to create a way to search a directory  by Imagetype or similiar variable.. before the image is uploaded to that diretory.

My goal is to search the BLOB of images in that directory with php, and if any result match (meaning there will duplicate uploads of the same image) return with "File already uploaded".

This will only pertain to image files...

Here is the code I think I can add too..

```
// Elements (values) of $_FILES['ImageFile'] array
//let's access these values by using their index position
$ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['ImageFile']['name'])); 
$ImageSize      = $_FILES['ImageFile']['size']; // Obtain original image size
$TempSrc        = $_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']; // Tmp name of image file stored in PHP tmp folder
$ImageType      = $_FILES['ImageFile']['type']; //Obtain file type, returns "image/png", image/jpeg, text/plain etc.

//Let's use $ImageType variable to check wheather uploaded file is supported.
//We use PHP SWITCH statement to check valid image format, PHP SWITCH is similar to IF/ELSE statements 
//suitable if we want to compare the a variable with many different values
switch(strtolower($ImageType))
{
    case 'image/png':
        $CreatedImage =  imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
        break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $CreatedImage =  imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
        break;          
    case 'image/jpeg':
    case 'image/pjpeg':
        $CreatedImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
        break;
    default:
        die('Unsupported File, Please Check File And Try Again!'); //output error and exit
}
```

Comment: Store meta data of each file in a database, and then try to look for it by taking meta data from the file to be uploaded? like type, size, dimentions, and some other common stuff

Comment: One of the pieces of metadata you should save is a hash of the contents.  That way you can tell if a file has been uploaded even under a different name.  And someone could replace a file with one of the same name if the content is different.

Comment: Would i still be able to leave the images in a directory on the server?

Comment: What if the image size as changed , or there is a minor alteration do you mean `exact image` or really ` identical images` ??? i just want to be clear

Comment: I don't anticipate many of my users to be uploading the same files under different names ETC. I just want it to be a catch if a user thinks their filed didn't upload i don't want it to be posted 2x.

This way I don't have to manually remove duplicated images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among other things, these have to be considered in such system :

1. User may upload the same filename, but with different contents (warn, update, replace, duplicate?)
2. User may upload the same file content, but under a different name (warn, update, replace, duplicate?)

In a system I had to design, a few years ago, files uploaded had to be replaced only on same user, different users could upload the exact same file name or content (it had to be linked to the existing file name to avoid duplicated data), but if the content was different, the file had to exist twice with the exact same name (assigned to two different users).

The Db table looked something like :

```
CREATE TABLE user_files (
   id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   ...   -- other fields
   filename VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,  -- the original file name
   file_sha VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,   -- the content SHA1
   file_md5 VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,   -- the content MD5
   file_lnk VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL, -- uniqid(sha1(originalFilename)) *
   ...   --- other fields
)
```

**[*]** the `file_lnk` field is the target file on the server, including a computed path based on some heuristics

Basically, I used [`sha1_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1-file.php) **and** [`md5_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php) on the uploaded file (still in the upload temp directly) and looked in the database for the uploaded file; The SHA1 or the current user id and file name (ie: `SELECT ... WHERE file_sha = <computed_sha1> OR (user_id = <current_uid> AND filename = <uploaded_filename>)`) was queried from the database to check for any match then looped through the resultset with an algorithm to check the best matching result :

- if the SHA1 matched anything then the content was probably already uploaded, the MD5 field was then compared also.

  - if the file belonged to the same user (same `user_id`), then `filename` was only updated if necessary
  - in any other case, the file content was to be linked and a new row was created in the database to the existing content (same `file_lnk`)
- if the `user_id` and `filename` was the same, then same file name was uploaded

  - if the same file content was linked with another user, a new row was created, generating a new `file_lnk` and updating `file_sha` and `file_md5`.
  - in any other case, and the file content was replaced with this new content (replacing the actual `file_lnk` file only)
- in any other case, a new file and db table row was created

Comment: Under what circumstances would two identical files result in matching SHA1s but not MD5s? If they have the same contents, the MD5s should match, as should the SHA1s.

Comment: @EzequielMuns, the SHA1 is only 40 bytes long, and I had files many MB uploaded. It was theoretically possible, although with slim chances, that two different content *could* return the same hashes. The MD5 was for safety checks only.